# searching comma separated list using SOSL with wild cards

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

Is it possible to use a SOSL query to search for Product Names in a comma separated list that still includes wildcards?

For example, if you input a search string like this: productA, productB, productC

Can I run a SOSL query that would return all products for %productA% and %productB% and %productC%?

Is that possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not comma separated ;)

"OR" is considered a keyword for searches (similar to SQL and SOQL). Here's a search similar to yours performed on dataset from my Developer Edition.

[image: Sample search result in Dev. Edition]

```
List<List<Sobject>> results = [FIND 'Burli* OR Uni*' 
    IN Name FIELDS 
    RETURNING Account (Id, Name) 
    LIMIT 2];
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(results[0]));

  DEBUG|[ {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/0017000000Lg8WgAAJ"
  },
  "Id" : "0017000000Lg8WgAAJ",
  "Name" : "University of Arizona"
}, {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/0017000000Lg8WbAAJ"
  },
  "Id" : "0017000000Lg8WbAAJ",
  "Name" : "Burlington Textiles Corp of America"
} ]
```

See [SOSL reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) for more goodies. If the samples on the bottom of the page will look off (all these curly braces) - rememeber that there's slight difference between SOQL called from say SOAP API and the one called from Apex code.